# C++ Reading UTF8 buffer using wide stream

Tags: c++, utf-8, inputstream, utf-16

My problem is that I have a buffer in utf8 format stored in a std::string. I want to supply it as a wistringstream to boost spirit. How can I do it without converting the whole std::string to std::wstring. I would like to have a stream that works as a readonly view from utf8 to whatever is wchar_t on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `u8_to_u32_iterator`. `wchar_t` is not enough for all characters. You can pass `int32` iterator to boost spirit functions as well or just write a wrapper, which would convert `int32` iterator to `wchar_t` iterator. Or use `u32_to_u16_iterator` for this purpose.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/internal_details/uni_iter.html